# I need to make a right triangle out of numbers

Tags: java

I can make this:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){

    for (int j=0; j<i; j++){

        System.out.print("*");
    }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

but I cannot find out how to write a static void method that receives a positive integer and uses nested for-loops to display a right triangle made up of integers 1 to the number received

Comment: What should the positive integer denote? The number of stars you want to print or the number of lines you want to print (the "height" of the triangle)?

Comment: its any positive integer a user inputs

Comment: For sure, but what is the meaning of the input? That is not clear from your question

Comment: if the integer is 4, the output would be:

Comment: 1, 1 2, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 1):

you can create static private method with size parameter and call from main method like below -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    makeTriangle(6);
}

private static void makeTriangle(int size){
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){

        for (int j=0; j<i; j++){

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define static method like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void printRightTriangle(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printRightTriangle(12);
    }
}
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to print a right-angled triangle made up of integers in a method that takes a positive int.

```
public static void printTriangle(int maxVal) {
    for (int i=1; i<=maxVal; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printRightTriangle(6);
}

public static void printRightTriangle(int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```